# display a set c that can not be enumerated

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory

Find a set $ C $ for which there are no injective functions from $ C $ to $\Bbb{N} $. (Hint: If there is an injective function, $ f: C \rightarrow  \Bbb{N} $ then the set $X $ would be enumerable. Display a set $ C $ that can not be enumerated.)

I do not know how to solve such problems.

Comment: What is $\mathbb{X}$? Usually the notaton $\Bbb{C}$ is used for the set of complex numbers. Hint: "really" think about a set which is uncountable.

Comment: @AnuragA: Well, the usual  $\mathbb C$ does work fine ...

Comment: Sorry for my notation maybe it was a bit confusing, X is an enumerable set because it's injective, C needs to be non-enumerable.

Comment: I edited to make it clearer

Comment: Possibly some confusion here with the lower-case $c$ that is often used to denote the cardinality of the continuum (i.e., $c = |\Bbb{R}|$).

Answer (score 1):

$\Bbb R$ would be such a set.  It's fairly easy to prove that $\vert\Bbb R\vert=\vert P(\Bbb N)\vert$.  And then Cantor's diagonal argument shows that $\vert P(\Bbb N)\vert\gt\vert\Bbb N\vert$.

Comment: So the set of $P ( \Bbb{N} ) $  is surjective in relation to the $ \Bbb{N} $  ?

Comment: It has larger cardinality.